# Fewer colors than specified by num_colors in choroplethr

Tags: r, choroplethr

num_colors often doesn't seem to be respected. A simple case of 9 states with 7 different values:

```r
> df
      region value
1    alabama     1
2    wyoming     5
3    arizona     5
4   arkansas     5
5 california     8
6   colorado    15
7       iowa    22
8       ohio    29
9    florida    36
> dput(df)
structure(list(region = c("alabama", "wyoming", "arizona", "arkansas", 
"california", "colorado", "iowa", "ohio", "florida"), value = c(1, 
5, 5, 5, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

A simple map where num_colors is 9 using a brewer color scale yields a legend with a separate color for each of the 7 values (Alaska and Hawaii don't work with this method, but that's another issue):

```r
library(choroplethr)
library(ggplot2)

g <- state_choropleth(df, num_colors = 9)
gg <- g + scale_fill_brewer(name="Count",palette="YlOrRd", drop=FALSE, na.value="grey")
gg
```

[image: 9 colors]

If I drop the number of colors to 7, the actual number of unique values in the data, the legend has only 5 colors. Two sets of values are binned, instead of none.
[image: 7 colors specified; 5 are used]

If I drop further to 5 colors, only 4 get used.
[image: 5 colors specified; 4 are used]

Specifying 6 colors results in 5, as 7 does, but binned differently from 7.

I can force it to use all 7 colors if I cut the data according to the values, in which case a lower num_colors value is ignored:

```
df$value <- cut (df$value, breaks = c(0,unique(sort(df$value))))
```

[image: # of colors forced by cuts]

My question then is why the specified number of colors doesn't get respected and is there a way to force that.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's several things going on here.

The easiest issue for me to address is that Hawaii and Alaska are not getting your custom scale applied to them (and so are appearing black). This is because choroplethr uses ggplot2's "custom annotation" feature to render them separately and then manually place there where Mexico is. And the way that custom annotations in ggplot2 work is that your `+ scale_fill_brewer()` call only gets applied to the main image (and not the custom annotations).

The way to get a custom scale to apply to all 3 images (continental US, Alaska and Hawaii) simultaneously is to use Choroplethr's Object Oriented features.

To see how they work, first look at how `state_choropleth` actually works:

```r
> state_choropleth # no parentheses

function(df, title="", legend="", num_colors=7, zoom=NULL, reference_map = FALSE)
{
  c = StateChoropleth$new(df)
  c$title  = title
  c$legend = legend
  c$set_num_colors(num_colors)
  c$set_zoom(zoom)
  if (reference_map) {
    if (is.null(zoom))
    {
      stop("Reference maps do not currently work with maps that have insets, such as maps of the 50 US States.")
    }
    c$render_with_reference_map()
  } else {
    c$render()
  }
}
<bytecode: 0x7fde42ffd910>
<environment: namespace:choroplethr>
```

And here is how to use those features to apply a custom scale to the annotations as well as the continental US:

```r
c = StateChoropleth$new(df)
c$set_num_colors(9)
c$ggplot_scale = scale_fill_brewer(name="Count",palette="YlOrRd", drop=FALSE, na.value="grey")
c$render()
```

[image]

I'm sorry, but I don't exactly understand the other issue you are reporting. One thing I will say is that binning was one of the more complex features to imlement (I am the author of choroplethr). It's not just the math of doing the binning, it's also making the labels appear nice. You can see the code for it [here](https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethr/blob/master/R/choropleth.R#L195).

One option in your case might be to convert the numbers to factors, and then feed them to choroplethr:

```r
df$value = as.factor(df$value)
state_choropleth(df)
```

[image]

I should also say that I cover issues like these in my online courses on choroplethr, all of which are now free. If you are interested in taking them, you can learn more [here](https://arilamstein.com/blog/2021/12/02/my-courses-are-now-free/).

Comment: Ari, thanks so much for the reply. I'm a big fan of the package, so thanks for that too!

Comment: I'm aware of the OO approach, but I haven't been using it, because it's not clear to me how to get the other bits of ggplot to work w/it. For example, how do I move the legend? The other issue is simply that num_colors just doesn't work they way I expect it to. That is, if I tell it to use 5 colors & there are >5 values to plot (so that 5 will work), there will often be <5 colors. I get that the binning is complicated, but for me the minimum result should be the # of colors I ask for. How they're binned is less important. (I should check the tutorial.)

Comment: @Eponymous Both your question and comment bring up more than a single issue. SO isn't really designed for that. I recommend posting a new question for each specific issue you are experiencing.

Comment: My original question was about the num_colors, not the OO stuff. :-) That feels like a single issue to me, but please let me know how to refine it and I will.

Comment: just bumping this: the single issue is the one in the title about the number of colors.

Comment: The single most important issue I saw in your original question is that you were writing `state_choropleth() + scale_fill_brewer()` for a map that included all 50 states. That is an error, as it leads to some states appearing black. I feel like I solved that. The problem I'm having with your question about num_colors is that you have multiple examples - this makes it hard for me to know where to start. Please create a new question that just has a single example of incorrect or confusing behavior regarding num_colors. That will make it easier for me (or someone else) to trace the code.

Comment: No problem. I'll make another question. But really here I'm just illustrating what happens as the number of colors - the thing I'm asking about - changes.